# Does a cache-as-ram have a starting address?

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-cache

It seems there are statements for setting up the cache lines as no-evict, but then how does the processor pick out which bytes in the cache line to use? Is it a specific addressing mode in the processor? Is it an MTRR overlaid memory address? Or, does the cache line behave as a FIFO, where the front of the line are the next words seen?

I'm studying the coreboot code for setting up cache-as-ram on x64.

I also read the answer given to a question "cache-as-ram (no fill mode)" and understanding about addressing was not addressed there.

Please excuse the naivete of my question, but the examples and discussion as to why it works are unclear to me.

Comment: It doesn't have its own address-space, it still works like usual ("caching" physical addresses) except that eviction can't happen because that only happens on fill.  So cache lines that have already been "filled" (state other than Invalid) will keep working.  If the memory controllers are enabled at all, you'd want to pick an address range backed by RAM I think.

Comment: So the instruction (in ROM, presumably) references a location in DRAM that is backed by the L1 cache, but because the cache is in no-evict mode that data is actually referenced in the cache, not the DRAM? Do I have that right?

Comment: Right, it works as a normal memory load or store that hits in cache. (I think potentially L3 cache, not just L1d if I recall correctly, but I haven't read about it for a while.)

Comment: But Coreboot sets that mode up prior to DRAM actually "existing yet", so the advantage is what?

Comment: My understanding is that it lets you store data and be guaranteed that a later load will get what you stored, instead of maybe zeros, garbage, or an error, within address-ranges that you primed ahead of enabling no-fill mode.  So it gives you way more storage space than just the register file before the DRAM controllers are up and running.

Comment: So if I read within the primed address ranges the read should be at the speed of the cache? Is it read only?

Comment: It's not read-only, it's cache-as-RAM not ROM.  That's the point, like I said before, to have somewhere to store data.  And yes, it should work at cache speeds; it works just like normal except that on (L3) cache miss it won't send a request to a memory controller.  (I'm guessing it will just read as 0s or something.)

Comment: That is very interesting. Could I even set the program counter to read from the range?  Can I set the memory mapping to any of the levels of cache? The coreboot example only showed L2. If I have different cores mapping ram sections to the same cache, is that a potential IPC?

Comment: @eternalsquire You need your code to initially be in the L2 or higher for it to be fetched from cache, the front-end doesn't fetch from the L1D, only from the L1I which is not directly writable. Putting lines in a specific level is not trivial and requires the use of the prefetch instructions and it's not always possible. Plus there's little benefit to it because the CPU will automatically use the L2 for lines evicted from L1 and any line that's invalid when entering CAR is wasted because there's no filling and you ideally want a full L1 (and possibly a full L2). The cache is coherent ...

Comment: ... and the coherency protocol doesn't need the RAM to backup its requests (the L3 is usually the "terminator") so you should be able to ping-pong a line between different cores but beware that you need all cores to have the line cached before entering CAR and that sibling threads share the same caches.